# Is commenting on the close status of a question constructive?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-comments

I recently saw [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335886/question-punctuation) that was closed, and I commented that the close reason was not appropriate for this question, as it was indeed about Stack Overflow.

But the comment got quickly deleted, presumably because it was flagged.

So here is my question: Is the comment section of a question the correct place to raise your objections about the close status of a question? Is this type of comment constructive?

My view is that it can be constructive towards eventually providing an answer, since it can affect future voters. On the other hand, it is not directly related to the topic of the question.

Comment: There’s nothing unconstructive about discussing why a question was closed; that a comment like that would get deleted isn’t the norm. What exactly did you write?

Comment: @Pekka웃: From memory, the comment was something like this: "Lol at the closevoters, what site is this question about if not Stack Overflow".

Comment: I remember my comment being deleted on the jQuery new version thread. Yes, people are too professional here. We have to deal with it :(

Comment: @user000001 that isn't a particular useful comment. Your comment can be seen as only making the close voters look ridiculous. Better is to extend your comment a bit for example by adding: *if this question needs to be closed is the current chosen reason the correct one?* or something along those lines. I would still feel bad about my wrong close vote but I would feel more encouraged to explain my reasoning. Don't make me look dumb.

Comment: @rere: I guess you have a point. Now that I read it again it does seed more condescending than necessary. I will try to be more polite in the future...

Comment: @user000001 If you feel a question is inappropriate closed, explain *why* it doesn't merit closure.  Just stating *that* it doesn't merit closure adds nothing.